# event.preventDefault affecting response.render in Node

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, forms

I have a form in my html view, `<form action="/" method="POST" id="compareForm">`and when I submit that form, my node controller would handle it and render a new view called results.

```
router.post('/', function(req, res) /*code*/ {res.render('results', {}}
```

I decided i wanted to customize the submit behavior so I did some jquery and by the looks of it, my submission makes it into router.post, but res.render does not seem to work. I took the example from https://api.jquery.com/submit/ to customize my submit but, I suspect event.preventDefault is causing the issue. If I comment it out I can do res.render...but it calls router.post twice, which is wrong.

Comment: Are you using an AJAX request to issue the `POST` request?

Comment: I am using Jquery post `var posting = $.post( url, { s: term } ); `  similar to the example Jquery has provided about .post

Comment: An AJAX/XHR request is not the same as a normal browser request, you are supposed to process the response data yourself (with JS code). Depending on what you mean with _"customize the submit behaviour"_, you can also let the browser continue with the form submission if you remove the call to `event.preventDefault()`.